# How to hash file with multiple algorithms at the same time in PHP?

Tags: php, file, hash, md5, sha1

I would like to hash a given file using multiple algorithms but now I'm doing it sequentially, like this:

```
return [
    hash_file('md5', $uri),
    hash_file('sha1', $uri),
    hash_file('sha256', $uri)
];
```

Is there anyway to hash that file opening only one stream and not N where N is the amount of algos I want to use? Something like this:

```
return hash_file(['md5', 'sha1', 'sha256'], $uri);
```

Comment: You would need a streaming hash implementation, which I'm not sure PHP has in its standard library. With that you could open the file, read a few bytes, update the hashes, and then finalise them when the file is read completely.

Comment: @deceze http://php.net/hash-init would be the closest for that. But I can't tell if that's faster in this scenario.

Comment: @Dormilich Yes, but that still forces you to do it sequentially, the solution would look more like what deceze suggests.

Comment: @Asur It allows you to re-use the file handle, that's IMO the closest you can achieve in PHP.

Comment: @Dormilich Ah yes, that actually looks like what I'm talking about. Asur, not sure what your reservations are against this. You instantiate three of those things, read the file a few bytes at a time and update all three hashes with the read data. This way you only need to read the file once.

Comment: I misinterpreted the documentation, so basically you open the file and walk it using `hash_update` function on every chunk, right?

Comment: I believe what you're saying is correct, yes. Would be good if you could post an answer when you have worked it out.

Comment: @deceze I'm already working on it, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open a file pointer and then use [hash_init()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-init.php) with [hash_update()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-update.php) to calculate the hash on the file without opening the file many times, then use [hash_final()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-final.php) to get the resulting hash.

```
<?php
function hash_file_multi($algos = [], $filename) {
    if (!is_array($algos)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('First argument must be an array');
    }

    if (!is_string($filename)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Second argument must be a string');
    }

    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Second argument, file not found');
    }

    $result = [];
    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($fp) {
        // ini hash contexts
        foreach ($algos as $algo) {
            $ctx[$algo] = hash_init($algo);
        }

        // calculate hash
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $buffer = fgets($fp, 65536);
            foreach ($ctx as $key => $context) {
                hash_update($ctx[$key], $buffer);
            }
        }

        // finalise hash and store in return
        foreach ($algos as $algo) {
            $result[$algo] = hash_final($ctx[$algo]);
        }

        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Could not open file for reading');
    }   
    return $result;
}

$result = hash_file_multi(['md5', 'sha1', 'sha256'], $uri);

var_dump($result['md5'] === hash_file('md5', $uri)); //true
var_dump($result['sha1'] === hash_file('sha1', $uri)); //true
var_dump($result['sha256'] === hash_file('sha256', $uri)); //true
```

Also posted to PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php#122549

Comment: I was writing the answer right now, but it's really similar to yours. Thank you very much!

Comment: This still reads the file N times, just with rewinding it instead of closing and opening it.

Comment: Could this use something like `$uri = gettype($file) == 'resource' ? stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'] : $file;` to allow both resources and uris?

Comment: You could check if already a stream resource ([is_resource](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-resource.php)/[get_resource_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php)) and then just reassign `$fp`, then it won't open another pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modification of [Lawrence Cherone's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49490944)* that reads the file only once, and works even for non-seekable streams such as `STDIN`:

```
<?php
function hash_stream_multi($algos = [], $stream) {
    if (!is_array($algos)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('First argument must be an array');
    }

    if (!is_resource($stream)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Second argument must be a resource');
    }

    $result = [];
    foreach ($algos as $algo) {
        $ctx[$algo] = hash_init($algo);
    }
    while (!feof($stream)) {
        $chunk = fread($stream, 1 << 20);  // read data in 1 MiB chunks
        foreach ($algos as $algo) {
            hash_update($ctx[$algo], $chunk);
        }
    }
    foreach ($algos as $algo) {
        $result[$algo] = hash_final($ctx[$algo]);
    }
    return $result;
}

// test: hash standard input with MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256
$result = hash_stream_multi(['md5', 'sha1', 'sha256'], STDIN);
print_r($result);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJNb9NAFLz7VwySJduSoaRSOJAgFFQQPZRLuIUq2nrX2aX2rtmPJgX1t4fnjd20pYeyB3u9s2/mzfh1stvv5x872SV10JVXRkMyJ9fOW8HadRsar/KUNRvj8AGryxLpASrwJwEtVSN/pdyaWctuh5vFCPbLS2u20GKLH@f6hjWKL@wmtEL7z7tKdL1knn1R1nmwAUAb6OtKgGlE3qyYRb675JGmFc4EW4l87Om/dZeiMpo/I4yR@4l0SueUScziANSGpCuJMSXmEHcPe0krv1vF00uqjAErrfyh5F6gf26lagS5q4Wpn7WVVjLoa2KpCeLjlRITzOc4fVvMgJMT9Bg48wxKE3ShPiHWuXuel7Tdr9hs6IiLYj7aKIdGhuaPBu5eHsohyie51Eqz5qHSo3is8MHqsXSW0F8ht144/z6Ww3mmObOcfHfBY6u8xMXZtMTy6@L1hAaKx93p9F1y/JX/Tvwqa/k0K5E5ySbDm2oy8r38fnb@jZrqrNJ@bfOBppjt9wv8Cqq6xhVNnqYMdvgZ2s7B3AhL8yjQsN@34Gbz5i8)

It works by reading the data from the input stream with [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) in chunks (of one megabyte, which should give a reasonable balance between performance and memory use) and feeding the chunks to each hash with [`hash_update()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-update.php).

<sup>*) Lawrence updated his answer while I was writing this, but I feel that mine is still sufficiently distinct to justify keeping both of them. The main differences between this solution and Lawrence's updated version are that my function takes an input stream instead of a filename, and that I'm using `fread()` instead of `fgets()` (since for hashing, there's no need to split the input on newlines).</sup>